# How to select JNDI based on environment

Tags: java, xml, spring, tomcat, jndi

Is it somehow possible to select a JNDI Resource based on the value of a variable containing which environment to link to ?

For example, in my domain I have 3 environments: DEV, QA and STAGE. I have a database called EcommReporting that exists for each of these environments. To cater for this, in my tomcat server's `server.xml` file, I have separate entries for `DEV_EcommReporting`, `QA_EcommReporting` and `STAGE_EcommReporting`.

The question is, is there some way my code can just request for the JNDI resource named `EcommReporting` and provides an environment name, and then based on these two details the correct Resource is returned ?

Here's now I'm defining a datasource bean using Spring:

```
   <bean id="EcommReportingDataSource" class="org.springframework.jndi.JndiObjectFactoryBean">
        <property name="jndiName" value="java:comp/env/jdbc/EcommReporting"/>
    </bean>
```

Then in my Tomcat server's context.xml (only showing the QA version), I have this:

```
<ResourceLink name="jdbc/EcommReporting"
                global="jdbc/QA_EcommReporting"
                auth="Container"
                type="javax.sql.DataSource" />
```

Lastly, in my Tomcat server's server.xml, I've defined the JNDI resource as follows:

```
<Resource name="jdbc/QA_EcommReporting" 
      global="jdbc/QA_EcommReporting" 
      auth="Container" 
      type="javax.sql.DataSource" 
      driverClassName="com.mysql.jdbc.Driver" 
      url="jdbc:mysql://URLHERE.COM:3311/REPORTING" 
      username="username_here" 
      password="password_here" 

      maxActive="100" 
      maxIdle="20" 
      minIdle="5" 
      maxWait="10000"/>
```

ads

Comment: it is not clear what you want, you have 3 instances of tomcat and you want to be able to access to the datasource used by those 3 instances from a different JVM, is it what you want?

Answer (score 1):

You could do something using Spring profiles. It is unclear what the exact setup is: sounds like all 3 WARs are deployed to the same server?? If so, you would need to set the active profile dynamically. One way I could think of would be to use a ServletContextListener and check the path of the deployed app.

Essentially then you create three dataSource beans and associate them with specific profiles. This process is outlined here:

https://spring.io/blog/2011/02/11/spring-framework-3-1-m1-released/

```
<beans profile="dev">
    <jee:jndi-lookup id="dataSource" jndi-name="java:comp/env/jdbc/Dev_EcommReporting"/>
</beans>
<beans profile="qa">
    <jee:jndi-lookup id="dataSource" jndi-name="java:comp/env/jdbc/QA_EcommReporting"/>
</beans>
```

You can then create a ServletContextListener and set the active profile based on the path.

```
    @Override
    public void contextInitialized(ServletContextEvent event) {

       ServletContext context = event.getServletContext();

       if(context.getContextPath().equals("/dev"){
           servletContext.setInitParameter("spring.profiles.active", "dev");
       } else if(context).getCOntextPath().equals("/qa"){
           servletContext.setInitParameter("spring.profiles.active", "qa");
       }
    }
```

More info here:

https://www.mkyong.com/spring/spring-profiles-example/

If all apps deployed to different servers then just start the server with -Dspring.profiles.active=xyz